# Select Row in Excel with VBA if complete

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I want to select each row that is complete. So each row where there is no empty cell. 
The selected row should then be exported to a sharepoint list.

so far the code I tried works but exports the whole table. I want to add a line that selects and exports only the rows that have no blank cells.

I had something like the following in mind. But I don't know how to select the complete rows from the entire table instead of specifying the cells.

`If Cells().Value not isnull then
Range().EntireColumn.Select`

```
Sub ExportToSharePoint ()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Publish Array("https://sharepoint...", "Name of the List")_, True

    ActiveCell.Select   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your table and get the completed rows using the following

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExportToSharePoint()
    Dim r
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
        For Each r In .DataBodyRange.Rows
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Parent.Range(r.Address)) = .ListColumns.Count Then
                ' Rest of your code here
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Additionally you could try to use the [Application.Union method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) to "collect" all  rows and publish at once. And a nice resource for how to use ListObject tables can be found here: [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)